# Qt Crypto - How to validate RSA key?

Tags: qt, authentication, rsa

I'm trying to use the [Qt Cryptographic Architecture](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/) to generate public/private key pairs for nodes, and want to have a protocol in which nodes confirm that a message came from a given source (public key) by issuing a challenge to ensure they are the owners of the corresponding private key. I'm a little stuck on the actual syntax for QCA though ...

This should get me a private key, from which I can also get the public key:

```
QCA::KeyGenerator generator;
QCA::PrivateKey privateKey = generator.createRSA(1024);
```

Does QCA already have some sort of challenge protocol built in? If so, how can I use it? If not, how can I apply some of the standard cryptographic challenge protocols using these keys?  I'm really just trying to demo a simple security concept - I'm not looking for anything complicated or even particularly robust.

Also, this is a side question, but since I don't need encryption, should I be opting for DSA as opposed to RSA?

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one of doing that. But since all clients already have their asymmetric key pairs you may deploy [two-way TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication) in establishing connection. 
In this scheme both client and server allow establishing connection only, if they trust certificates (public keys) of each other. This guarantees client authentication and non-repudiation.

From your side you will need to provision server certificate to all clients and all client certificates to the server. To avoid dealing with certificate authorities, certificates could be self-signed.

QCA has examples for TLS [client](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=qca.git&a=tree&h=01cd367580b220d340f0e7467136ae4e292b7a0e&hb=a67d31b1ecdb338eb6508f05f30520b8da4d869f&f=examples%2Fsaslclient) and [server](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=qca.git&a=tree&h=64e6b507224c9d8f871486b4e3949dc698fc0d19&hb=a67d31b1ecdb338eb6508f05f30520b8da4d869f&f=examples%2Fsaslserver).